# How to submit a perforce CL of another user without admin privileges?

Tags: perforce

I don't have admin privileges. Need to test other's change lists and submit them.
Tried changing the owner of the CL but didn't work without admin.

```
p4 change -U <creator> <CL>
Error in change specification.
Change <CL> can only be updated by user <creator>
```

Unshelving the original CL, then testing it, will create a duplicate CL. Duplicate CL is submittable but not the original CL.

Are there any ways to submit a perforce change list of another user without admin privileges?

Comment: This feels like an "XY problem".  What problem are you trying to solve by submitting the "original" changelist rather than a functionally equivalent "duplicate"?

Comment: Actual problem: dev creates a CL >> tester took the CL >> run some tests on it >> if passes then submit else notify the dev. 
Need to submit the original CL as if in future something fails due to this CL, everyone will ask the tester, not the dev.

Comment: This feels like it'd be better accomplished by a review mechanism where the dev submits after the test has passed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on documentation I'd say no (see below). The way you are doing it is probably the best way using shelving. Another option would be to have an unstable branch that code is okay to be broken and another user can 'release' after testing to a stable branch.

From my understanding, changelists are owned by the user and not really "transferable" like you want.

From Helix 2020.2 documentation on the `p4 change` command

> The owner of an empty pending changelist (that is, a pending changelist without any files in it) can transfer ownership of the changelist to another existing user either by editing this field, or by using the -U user option.

If you start down the "sharing a workspace" path. Don't.  "It is actively discourages by Perforce Technical Support" and "it is almost never a good idea to share a Perforce client workspace among multiple users" https://community.perforce.com/s/article/3675

Comment: After posting the question I thought of trying one thing,
creator change the owner of the CL to the tester, then tester tests the CL and submit.
But need to change back the owner to the creator after submitting the CL.
Is there any way to do that?

Comment: According to the docs, it seems like the CL must be empty to transfer it unfortunately. It is kind of how Perforce works the server keeps tabs on everything and the clients let the server know about changes. Two clients don't communicate to each other directly.